# Anchor tags in URL with PHP variables?

Tags: php

I have an anchor tag in my page as such:

```
<div name="anchor">
```

I want to include a link to this anchor in a url that is also populated with PHP vars, eg:

```
mysite.com/index.php?id=60&teamid=105#anchor
```

But this does not work. I have also tried:

```
mysite.com/index.php#anchor?id=60&teamid=105
```

But no luck there either.

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The first one should work. Explain in what way it doesn't, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<div id="anchor">
```

and

```
mysite.com/index.php?id=60&teamid=105#anchor
```

The number sign points to ids - not names.